# Vue game: canvas not cleared

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

With Vue, I am creating the classic snake game.

I am not able to make the snake to move in different directions. And after clicking the button, the canvas is not cleared despite clear() function. What am I missing?

*Fiddle link*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnakeCanvas.vue Line 104

Change

```
this.boardContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.boardSizePx, this.boardSize);
```

to

```
this.boardContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.boardSizePx, this.boardSizePx);
```

Comment: do you know why it  does not move when pressing down the keys? @ani1998ket

Comment: @learnjspsde line 123 i think you should have used event.keyCode instead of KeyCode. Trying logging values before using them, will prevent you from bugs like these.

Comment: @learnjspsde `const newDirection = Constants.find((c) => c.keyCode === event.keyCode);`

Comment: @learnjspsde Could you please accept the answer, otherwise it seems like an open question which requires another answer. :D

Comment: sorry for late action, now it's accepted!